# Cant get color of pixel where i clicked at assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, interrupt, x86-16

im trying to get my program to give me the color of the pixel i clicked on.

From what i understood i use the ah=0dh and int 10h to get the color of the current pixel based on the CX and DX values which represent what X and Y. I divided the CX by 2 to get the accurate position. Yet each time i get the value its always wrong.

Can anybody please help me? thanks

```
proc playerTurn
       mov ax, 0h ;Reset mouse
       int 33h
       
       mov ax, 1h ;Display mouse to user
       int 33h
       
click:
       mov ax, 3h ;Result to be displayed in BX, is LSB=1 Left click, if left to LSB=1 Rightclick
       int 33h    ;If both = 0, no click at all
                  ;CX holds column coordinate, 0-629, must divide by 2 because graphic is 320
                  ;DX holds row coordinate 0-199
      
      cmp bx, 0
      je click
      
      shr cx, 1 ; divide cx by 2
      mov bh, 0 ; page number = 0
      
          
      mov ah, 0Dh ; get color from current CX DX and store value in AL
      int 10h 
      
      cmp randomNum, 49
      je checkBlue
      cmp randomNum, 50
      je checkGreen
      cmp randomNum, 51
      je checkRed
      cmp randomNum, 52
      je checkYellow
      jmp wrong
      
      
checkBlue:
  cmp al, 69h
  jne wrong
  call pressBlue
  jmp endTurn
checkGreen:
  cmp al, 79h
  jne wrong
  call pressGreen
  jmp endTurn
checkRed:
  cmp al, 70h
  jne wrong
  call pressRed
  jmp endTurn
checkYellow:
  cmp al, 74h
  jne wrong
  call pressYellow
  jmp endTurn

wrong:
          mov dx, offset wrongColor
          mov ah, 09h
          int 21h
endTurn:
      ret


playerTurn endp
```

Comment: Does getting the mouse cursor position or getting the pixel color give wrong values? Or do you have problems setting the current pixel position?

Comment: Reading [pixel color](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0105.htm) is not valid in text videomodes. If you have set the [graphic videomode 0Eh 640x200](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm),  then reading the [mouse position](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-5959.htm) should return column 0..639, no need to half it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While waiting for the user to either left- or right click, you should not just compare BX to zero! The bits that do not correspond to a mouse button (left=1, right=2, middle=4) are 'undefined'. This means that a mouse handler can store additional info (or even garbage) in those bits if it wanted so. The way to check for a left- or right click is:

```
test bx, 3
jz   click    ; Neither left, nor right click
```

Your understanding about the BIOS.ReadGraphicsPixel function 0Dh is correct. From the included tail comments, I deduce that you are working on the 320x200 256-color graphics screen. Halving the value that was returned in the CX register therefore is good. AL will contain a color value in the range [0,255].

It is possible that none of your color tests run because of that special block that you can't pass if a certain *randomNum* is not in the very limited range [49,52]. Only you know what purpose it serves. My guess is that your program does not pass at that point.

The color tests are using these unusual values {69h=Blue, 79h=Green, 70h=Red, 74h=Yellow} that represent pastelcolors. Are you sure those same color codes were used to draw the screen; the 'usual' values being {01h=Blue, 02h=Green, 04h=Red, 0Eh=Yellow}?

You should try next code and find out if my guess about the *randomNum* block was right:

```
proc playerTurn

    mov  ax, 0000h  ; ResetMouse
    int  33h        ; -> AX BX
    mov  ax, 0001h  ; ShowMouse
    int  33h
click:
    mov  ax, 0003h  ; GetMousePosition
    int  33h        ; -> BX CX DX     
    test bx, 3
    jz   click      ; Neither left, nor right click

    shr  cx, 1
    mov  bh, 0      ; page number = 0
    mov  ah, 0Dh
    int  10h        ; -> AL
      
    mov  di, OFFSET pressBlue
    cmp  al, 69h
    je   OK
    mov  di, OFFSET pressGreen
    cmp  al, 79h
    je   OK
    mov  di, OFFSET pressRed
    cmp  al, 70h
    je   OK
    mov  di, OFFSET pressYellow
    cmp  al, 74h
    je   OK
NOK:mov  dx, OFFSET wrongColor
    mov  ah, 09h
    int  21h
    ret
OK: jmp  di         ; `call di` `ret`

playerTurn endp
```

Comment: I deeply appreciate your help and for sharing your knowledge with us!